# htaccess esconder parametros modelo MVC

Tags: php, htaccess, mvc

Eu tenho o seguinte URL:

`http://192.168.1.67/plays/mvc/index.php?route=profile&user=mikas.28`

Em que route = PAGINA e user = USERNAME.USERID

tenho o seguinte htaccess

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /plays/mvc

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

E o que consegui foi:

`http://192.168.1.67/plays/mvc/profile&user=mikas.28`

Funcionou para eliminar `index.php?route=`, tentei acrescentar outras rules que se adequassem para eliminar os outros mas não consegui.

O meu objectivo é alcançar `http://192.168.1.67/plays/mvc/profile/mikas.28`

Se isto for alcançado tenho de alterar alguma coisa no meu index.php?

```
$router = new Router();

if(isset($_GET['route'])) {
   $route = $_GET['route'];
}
else {
   $route = 'home';
}


if(!is_null($router->get($route))) {

   $r = $router->get($route);
   $controllerName = $r['controller'];
   $methodName = $r['method'];

   require_once "controllers/" .$controllerName. '.php';
   $controller = new $controllerName();
   $controller->$methodName();

}

else {
   echo "404 Not Found!";
}
```

Comment: ja tive esse tipo de problema porém não consegui resolver, tomara que alguém nos responda!! Excelente pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado, ando sempre às voltas com htaccess

Comment: @KaduAmaral consegui adequar essa resposta ao meu caso. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui:

htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/)([^/]+)$ index.php?route=$1&user=$3 [L]
```

index.php:

```
$router = new Router();

if(isset($_GET['route'])) {
   $route = $_GET['route'];
   $route = explode("/", $route)[0];
}
else {
   $route = 'home';
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

A regra de re-escrita está mal escrita.
Em vez de:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

Escreva:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/)([^/]+)$ index.php?route=$1&user=$3 [L]
```